# Unbolding Layer names in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, font, qgis-2

I am currently working with QGIS 2.0 in an Ubuntu environment. I have a quite large project with many different layers and layer-groups. By default the layernames are in bold fonts and the groups are not. I guess it would be more convenient if it would be the other way around.

Is there *any* possibility to change it?

The setting in "general" -> "bold group box titles" is not the thing I want, as it makes the font within the settings menu for groups bold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are very close, just on the wrong tab!

Go Settings->Options->Canvas & Legend and set 'Bold group names' to true and 'Bold layer names' to false.

You've got a few other options to play with here too (like capitalising the layer names and displaying the classification attribute names), which might be useful for you too.