# QGIS 3 bold Layer names?

Tags: qgis, layers, font, qgis-3

In QGIS 2 the Option for bold Layernames was here:

*Go Settings->Options->Canvas & Legend and set 'Bold group names' to true and 'Bold layer names' to false.*

This link helps provide context. [QGIS 2 bold Layer names?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72683/qgis-2-bold-layer-names)

**How is that working for QGIS 3.4 ?
Couldn't find that option somehow.**

Comment: It looks like this option was dropped in QGIS 3.4.

Comment: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Legend-layer-customization-missing-td5362120.html